# selecting list only words witj latin letter in R

Tags: r, tm

Say there is data

```
text=c(車、,男,犬, sba, druzhba)
```

How can i get list only with words with latin letter

Here

```
sba
druzhba
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringr` package can be used for this.  See ?"stringi-search-charclass" for details about how to use unicode properties.

```
text=c("車","男","犬", "sba", "druzhba")

library(stringr)
text[str_detect(text, "[\\p{Letter}&&\\p{script=latin}]")]
```